# Pull up/push down the negation in IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

In *Eclipse*, there has long been a "Pull negation up"/"Push negation down" quick fix:

[image]

How can I do the same in *IDEA*? It looks like the intention is not there:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not obvious but you will get the exact same result with `"Replace '&&' with '||'`.

In *IntelliJ*, it is called **De Morgan’s Laws** which is the intention to reverse a given `boolean` expression to switch from `&&` to `||` and vise & versa.

More details about what are the **De Morgan’s Laws** [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/09/the-inspection-connection-issue-2/).

Comment: Indeed. In *IDEA*, it's also possible to push the negation down, but it seems a little counter-intuitive at the first glance. One has to select *precisely* the expression inside the parentheses: `p0 || p1`. If the enclosing parentheses (and, optionally, the leading negation) are additionally selected: `!(p0 || p1)`, the **DeMorgan Law** intention doesn't show up.